# install WIX installer application in C: partition instead of Program Files folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, wix

I have created a installer using WIX in VS2010.Currently when i install the application,it is installing the application and application related dependency files under `C:\Program Files\Wixdemoapplication`. I need to customize this.I need to install the application directly under `Wixdemoapplication` under `C:\Wixdemoapplication` and not `C:\Program Files\Wixdemoapplication`.

Need help.

Comment: You need to set the INSTALLFOLDER property to wherever you want to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested; but probably enough for what you need to do):

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Wixdemoapplication" />
</Directory>
```

Otherwise, can do some other fun stuff, like:

Add this custom action to Product.wxs:

```
<CustomAction Id="SpawnBrowseFolderDialog" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="SpawnBrowseFolderDialog" Return="check" />
```

Add this into button in some dialog in Product.wxs:

```
<Control Id="BrowseButton" Type="PushButton" X="276" Y="126" Width="90" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}B&amp;rowse..." TabSkip="no">
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SpawnBrowseFolderDialog"><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
    <Publish Property="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>
```

Add this custom action in (right click solution, add, new project, C# Custom Action project):

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SpawnBrowseFolderDialog(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Started the SpawnBrowseFolderDialog custom action.");
    try
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.Description = "Please select an installation directory to house core files and components.";
            dialog.SelectedPath = session["INSTALLFOLDER"];
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            session["INSTALLFOLDER"] = dialog.SelectedPath;
        });
        worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        session.Log("Exception while trying to spawn the browse folder dialog. {0}", exception.ToString());
    }
    session.Log("Finished the SpawnBrowseFolderDialog custom action.");
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: TARGETDIR should be avoided because it's variable. And there's no need for a custom action when directory selection is built in to MSI.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<Directory>` element for your program nested under a `<Directory Id="WindowsVolume">`.